# Почему subdivision surfaces ломает модель?

Tags: 3d, blender

Предупреждаю: я полный профан в блендере и делал модель по туториалу, но у парня всё было нормально с этим модификатором.

У меня имеется низкополигональная модель ножа, в данный момент я работаю над лезвием. До применения модификатора "subdivision surfaces" модель выглядит следующим образом:[image: Лезвие до применения модификатора]

После добавления модификатора начинается полный кошмар и лезвие превращается в какую-то аморфную кучу из полигонов:
[image: После]

Каким образом можно решить эту проблему и заставить модификатор адекватно сглаживать модель?

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что не все нормали граней вашего объекта направлены наружу. Можете проверить это, включив отображение ориентации граней (Overlay - Face orientation). Если проблема в этом, то необходимо для объекта в режиме редактирования выделить все (или только нужные) грани, нажатием Alt+N вызвать меню и выбрать в нём пункт Recalculate Outside. После нормализации граней подразделение должно работать нормально.